# Java - Upload file using POST to URL then retrieve response

Tags: java, http, url, post

I want to upload a file (GPX file, which is similar to XML) to a URL (http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map_input). Then wait for the map to be generated and retrieve it. The developer has stated this is possible, but I am not getting anywhere.
Here is my code so far:

```
private static void postData(File fileName) {
    File input = fileName;

    //Setup connection
    URL url = new URL("http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 1.2.30703)");

    //Send file
    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(input);
    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(fileReader);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(os);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    os.flush();

    //Retrieve response
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(  
    new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));  
    String line = br.readLine();  
    while ( line != null ) {  
        System.out.println(line);  
        line = br.readLine();  
    }  
    br.close();
}
```

All this is doing, is setting up the connection, when I get the response, I am only getting the HTML of the initial page, not the (should be) map one.

Comment: Is the map embedded in the html? The InputStream from `connection` will contain everything in the body of the HTTP response. You have to parse it and extract what you want.

Comment: The map is embedded, but surely when I retrieve the full response, the code will be in there, but it isn't.

Comment: Then that probably means your POST was incorrect, maybe missing some parameters. Looking at the link you posted, there's a bunch of form parameters. You should fill those in.

Comment: Maybe I'm going at this completely wrong then. Normally, using the GPX file I created, I would upload it onto that site manually, then select Draw a Map. This then opens up a new page with the map. How can I replicate this method in code?

Comment: When you click the `Draw the map` button, your browser attaches the different input parameters included in the enclosing form to your Http Post request. If you're going to send the same request through java code, you need to put those parameters in yourself. Use a tool like Firebug to find out which parameters are needed and write those  into your request. Look into multipart requests since you are doing a file upload.

Comment: All the other parameters are in the file. So surely I just need the file parameters?

Comment: Parameters for your map, yes. But a web server needs to know where the request came from and to do that it looks at other parameters from the request. For example, the button in the form is an input `submit` parameter that has to be in the request.

Comment: Good news, the parameter for the file is "uploaded_file_1". How would I put a file into a parameter?

Comment: It's a little complicated with file uploads. Do a search for multipart http requests in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised I was almost doing this correctly.
After speaking to the developer of the website, I realised I could send the GPX file as a String. (This is very simple)
I then put this String into parameters which worked a treat!

```
String data = URLEncoder.encode("data", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("convertedGPX", "UTF-8");

OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();
```