# HTTPRequest connection seccessful but the file was not uploaded

Tags: java, http, post, http-post, httprequest

I was making POST request with http request from `java.net.http.HttpRequest` and other necessary packages.

My intend was inserting .wav file with post request.

Connection was success but the file was not uploaded.

I've searched and read google and Oracle docs a lot.

Here's my code:

```
HttpClient uploadClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .build();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                 .uri(URI.create(uploadAddress))
                 .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                 .header("Content-Type", "audio/wav")
                 .POST(BodyPublishers.ofFile(file.toPath()))
                 .build();
        
        HttpResponse<?> response = uploadClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding());
```

Am I heading right way?

Now I'm wondering that do I have to use `HttpURLConnection` package instead of these codes.

I read these resources:

[Java - Upload file using POST to URL then retrieve response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663586/java-upload-file-using-post-to-url-then-retrieve-response)

[Upload files from Java client to a HTTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469451/upload-files-from-java-client-to-a-http-server)

[how to (simply) generate POST http request from java to do the file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314300/how-to-simply-generate-post-http-request-from-java-to-do-the-file-upload)

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.html#ofFile(java.nio.file.Path)

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.Builder.html#POST(java.net.http.HttpRequest.BodyPublisher)

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.html

https://zetcode.com/java/getpostrequest/

I also read all the links that StackOverflow recommended.

I assume the problem is on the client side because server gave me response 200 with nullException at the body part. So I saw log and it says that the file was not uploaded. The exception I throws IOException, InterruptedException, JSException, URISyntaxException. The URL was address-to-access:port/path-to-upload. There are code handling the received file on the server side.

Comment: Why do you assume the problem is on the client side?

Comment: It's hard to tell what might be going wrong here without more information. I assume you're not getting any exception, right? So what url did you send the request to, what response do you get and how do you figure the file was not uploaded? Is there any code handling the received file on the server side?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your think. I assume the problem is on the client side because server gave me response 200 with nullException at the body part. So I saw log and it says that the file was not uploaded. The exception I throws IOException, InterruptedException, JSException, URISyntaxException. The URL was http://address-to-access:port/path-to-upload. There are code handling the received file on the server side.

Comment: @Sey looks like a problem with the url then. Did you put `http://` or `https://` at the beginning of the url?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. OTL